# Clear cell edit when change list

Tags: angular, primeng

when I reset and change the parameters to my tables I want to reset the cell edit because when I change the table de row edition keep going active.

This is my code when the list is changed.

```
@ViewChild('table', {static: true}) private _table;
```

```
this.listservice.getConfiguration(this.param)
      .subscribe(result => {
        result.data.forEach((element, index) => {
            resultData.push({id : index, element, ...element});
        });
        this._table.closeCellEdit(); // this is the funcion close cell 
        this.title = result.config.description;
        this.cols = result.config.cols;
        this.rows = resultData;
        this.selectedColumns = this.cols;
        this.numberElements = this.rows.length;
        this.optionsTypecontrol(this.cols);
        this.clonedRow = {};
    });
```

And this is the error log

```
ERROR TypeError: this._table.closeCellEdit is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (list.component.ts:98)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
```

This is not exactly my code, but is the oficial from primng and is the same structure. I put this because my original code is very long.

```
<p-table [value]="cars" dataKey="vin" editMode="row">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th style="width:8em"></th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-editing="editing" let-ri="rowIndex">
        <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData">
            <td>
                {{rowData.vin}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.year" year>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.year}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <p-dropdown [options]="brands" [(ngModel)]="rowData.brand" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></p-dropdown>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.brand}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.color">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.color}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" class="ui-button-info" (click)="onRowEditInit(rowData)"></button>
                <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" class="ui-button-success" style="margin-right: .5em" (click)="onRowEditSave(rowData)"></button>
                <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="onRowEditCancel(rowData, ri)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

The only thing you have to look at this html is the element html

```
<p-cellEditor>
```

and

```
<button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger closeedit" (click)="onRowEditCancel(rowData, ri)"></button>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code? and where are you calling the service, maybe on the ngOnInit method?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question)*.

I know it is possible there are better solution but the urgency of the moment requires it.

The solution is when change the list in the observable get alls buttons with class **closeedit** and click.

```
const a: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('.closeedit');
a.forEach(i => i.click());
```